# Is it possible to permit automatic bluetooth pairing with a RaspberryPi 4 which has neither a keyboard or a screen attached?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi4

I have a RaspberryPi 4 (with a Bluetooth adapter) that I wish to act as a peripheral that other devices (a phone or a desktop pc for example) can pair with. During development I currently have both a screen and keyboard attached to the Pi, but the goal is to have neither eventually (i.e. headless), and for the Pi to automatically accept the pairing request.

It seems that the appropriate Bluetooth agent to use on the Pi for this situation is 'NoInputNoOutput'.

Since there is an open bug when attempting to use the NoInputNoOutput agent with the latest RaspberryPi OS 11 bundled Bluez library 5.55 https://github.com/RPi-Distro/repo/issues/291 I am using the RaspberryPi OS version 10 with has the Bluez library version 5.50 (although please note that I have tried this with both OS versions)

Given the bluetooth is already powered on I am attempting to use bluetoothctl on the Pi like this
`:~ bluetoothctl`
`[bluetooth]# agent NoInputNoOutput`
`[bluetooth]# default-agent`
`[bluetooth]# pairable on`
`[bluetooth]# discoverable on`

The bluetoothctl 'show' command then indicates this configuration was successful and at this stage I can see 'raspberrypi' as an option to pair with on both my Android phone and my Mac.

However, when I attempt to connect using my Android phone I see the response "Couldn't connect", and on the Pi (in bluetoothctl) I see "Connected: yes" and then soon afterwards "Connected: no"

And when I attempt to connect from my Mac I get the dialog a dialog like this:
[image]
...but if I click 'Connect' then the pairing is unsuccesful and once more I see on the Pi (in bluetoothcl) "Connected: yes" and then soon "Connected: no"

Is this approach feasible/correct, and have I made any mistakes in my attempt to set this up?

Comment: Use `btmon` to find out whats going wrong.